# Downloading code from Ibm bluemix using cloud foundry?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

Hi guys my computer just died and I have lost all my files, Now I was using IBM Bluemix to make a node js application so all my files are on the IBM Bluemix space but I somehow can't seem to download my files that are there. It lets you download starter code but it doesn't let you download any recent pushes using cloud foundry. I'm really stuck at this any help will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a node.js application, you could also use the Bluemix file viewer to access the files directly from the application and download them. Just choose "Files" from the UI menu on the left, and navigate to the "app" directory. Your application files should be there. You can view them by clicking on them, and then download them with the little down arrow icon in the upper right:

[image: Bluemix file navigator]

Comment: Thanks Marc i'm up and running now, That button is tucked away couldn't really see it haha.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cf-download plugin [1]

[1] https://github.com/ibmjstart/cf-download

Answer (score 1):

I just learned this Cloud Foundry way to access the app (each app is a User in the Linux VM) in details. You need to install Cloud Foundry CLI - https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/cf-cli/install-go-cli.html and use an installer for your platform.

1. After installed **cf cli**, then one way is first to log into your
   api end point (the path before the command prompt > are just my path
   to a local server/pc) typically where the downloaded / local app
   codes are located:

   ```
   L:\IBM Cloud\PythonFlaskLab>cf login

   Email> rpoon@abrs.net

   Password> xxxxxxxxx
   Authenticating...
   OK 

   L:\IBM Cloud\PythonFlaskLab>cf api https://api.ng.bluemix.net
   Setting api endpoint to https://api.ng.bluemix.net...
   OK
   ```
2. Next:
   **cf ssh**  with your usual username and pw.  (cf is the Cloud Foundry CLI that you can download and install)

   after you login, it is like a Linux VM with your app as user name:
3. **An example** is shown below:

   ```
    L:\IBM Cloud\PythonFlaskLab>cf ssh CommunityPythonFlaskTrialLR

    vcap@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:~$ dir

    app  deps  logs  staging_info.yml  tmp

    vcap@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:~$ cd app

    vcap@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:~/app$ dir

    LICENSE  manifest.yml  NOTICE  Procfile  README.md  requirements.txt  static    welcome.py
   ```

You can use Linux scp to send to whatever PC or server with a FQDN name.

4. You can use:  **cf apps**   to view all your apps

   ```
   L:\IBM Cloud\PythonFlaskLab>cf apps
   Getting apps in org rpoon@abrs.net / space dev as rpoon@abrs.net...
   OK

   name                              requested state   instances   memory   disk   urls
   abrsserver1                       started           1/1         32M      1G    abrsserver1.mybluemix.net
   Community Python Flask Trial LR   started           1/1         128M     1G     Community-Python-Flask-Trial-LR.mybluemix.net
   RPcourseraIOT                     started           1/1         256M     1G     RPcourseraIOT.mybluemix.net
   ```

This would be a more manual process (compared with the plug in which yet to try out) but it let you know what is going on under the hood or edit your app directly on the cloud vm or for trouble shooting and move around. Getting to know the Linux details really is really helpful for me to open the hood cover if I want to.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access your application through the dashboard, did you create a Git repository for it?  If not, you can click the "Add Git" button and see your code in DevOps.
[image]

To download to your local workstation, you can run the git clone command and copy the files from your project Git Repository URL.

Comment: Thanks Valerie, Going to use DevOps services from now on wards.