# How I can download/pull deployed apps and services from Cloud Foundry on IBM Cloud/Bluemix?

Tags: node.js, curl, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, diego

The app (Node.js) is deployed on Cloud Foundry (IBM Cloud, US-South) by my previous colleague, but the codes in our private Github (seperate from IBM DevOps) for local testing doesn't look the same as what he has deployed on Cloud Foundry. I have tried the following methods to download it from the cloud, but none of them work:

1. Bluemix file viewer - I can't find it in the new IBM Cloud interface. How can I use DevOps services to achieve it? [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34757383/downloading-code-from-ibm-bluemix-using-cloud-foundry)
2. bx cf download - it doesn’t work because the app is running on Diego backend. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421474/is-it-possible-to-download-all-files-of-an-application-in-cloud-foundry)
3. bx cf file - it doesn’t work because the app is running on Diego backend. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421474/is-it-possible-to-download-all-files-of-an-application-in-cloud-foundry)
4. bx cf curl - I got the following error message. After I closed the firewall, the error message is still the same. I can't find a way to solve this problem. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39365778/how-to-download-the-app-with-the-cli-from-the-swisscom-app-cloud)

> Invoking 'cf curl /v2/apps/7fe6cdb8-521f-4716-954d-d9598502d049/droplet/download'...
>
> FAILED
>
> Error creating request:
>
> Error performing request: Get https://dal05.objectstorage.service.networklayer.com:443/v1/AUTH_9832c938-360c-442a-9713-a5ad3a5d5368/cc-droplets/20/ef/20efe5fb%!D(MISSING)0fa9%!D(MISSING)4ceb%!D(MISSING)8098%!D(MISSING)ec710c8ad0db/fb2ea5e85ec02b65e1d987a7223b92c414df5851?temp_url_sig=8e2b2f7ce7a420d323a0ed5f002669a095af5b12&temp_url_expires=1517896403: dial tcp 10.1.129.3:443: getsockopt: connection refused
>
> TIP: If you are behind a firewall and require an HTTP proxy, verify the https_proxy environment variable is correctly set. Else, check your network connection.

5. Cloud Object Storage - I don't have permission. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45936117/how-to-download-node-application-source-code-deployed-as-a-cloud-foundry-app-i)
6. SSH without CLI - It doesn't make sense to ask my password because I use a federated user ID without a password. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499625/how-to-pull-files-from-cloud-foundry-on-diego)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make 'bx cf ssh ' to the runtime. Then you should be able to make tar package of what you see necessary. Then just have a place to upload that to.

Comment: `bx cf ssh` works fine for me, and I am also federated.

Comment: Thanks @jarkko. I found that I can use SCP without CLI to copy files. Even though it's pretty slow but it works. But I still don't know how to copy/transfer files to local when I ssh.

Comment: I don't remember if I've ever used, but it seems to have scp at cloud side. But that requires the destination you copy to - needs to be open to internet. Another thing, if you have static resources folder open in the app, technically you could place the tar pkg there and just wget that into your local system. Wouldn't exactly recommend that, but technically that should also work.

Comment: For reference on using scp,sftp or rsync -> https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-apps.html#other-ssh-access